# htaccess rewrite url to remove htm extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have following site structure

```
- root 
    - de/
    - en/
```

Each folder contains some .htm files. E.g

```
en/products.htm
```

Insteand of

```
mysite.com/en/products.htm
```

I want to display in url bar

```
mysite.com/someEnglishTitle/products
```

Actually I want to relplace the language key with some string. My htaccess looked like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^/?$ /en/index.htm [L,R]
```

And I added

```
RewriteRule ^/english-books/products$ /en/products.htm [L,R]
```

But this does not work. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use the [L,R] in this case
L means Last, so no more rules are applied after this one does
R means Redirect, but you dont want that to happen, if the URL is to stay in the browser

So

```
RewriteRule ^english-books/products$ /en/products.htm
```

will mean that http://mysite.com/english-books/products will show the content of the file en/products.htm without changing the URL in the browser. Note that there is no trailing slash at the beginning

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to rewrite `/$var1/$var2` into `/$var1/$var2.htm` then try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-z0-9-_]+)/([a-z0-9-_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /%1/%2.htm
```